# Perturbing each argument of an anonymous function individually

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

If I have a function with 2 arguments, e.g.:

[image: formula]

and I want to create a vector of functions where the `i`th element holds `f` with a perturbation of the `i`th argument:

[image: formula]

I can do this as follows:

```
f = @(x) x(1) + x(2)^2 ;
eps = 1e-10;  
g = @(x) [];
for i = 1:2
    f_i = @(x) f([x(1) - eps * (i == 1), x(2) - eps * (i == 2)]);
    g = @(x) [g(x), f_i(x)];
end
```

Is there a way to do this using anonymous functions for a function with `k` arguments? For example if my function were:

[image: formula]

**EDIT**

`(x1, ..., xk)` are parameters that I need to estimate, i.e. `x_opt = fminunc(@(x) g(x) * eye(k) * g(x)', zeros(k, 0))` and not known values.

**Note**: The answer should be applicable to any functional form (e.g. `f = @(x) x(1)^x(2)` in which case I would want `g = @(x) [(x(1) - eps)^x(2), x(1)^(x(2) - eps)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MATLAB you often don't need to create such functions. Instead you can work with vectors and matrices.

You can define `(x1,x2,...)` as a vector of values:

```
X = [x1 x2 x3 ... xk];
```

and instead of `f = [x1^1 x2^2 ...]` you can write:

```
k = numel(X);
f= X.^(1:k);
```

For `g` you can create a `[k * k]` matrix that each row represents a function:

```
Eps = 1e-10;
g = repmat(f,k,1);
```

then multiply the diagonal elements by `Eps`;

```
g(1:k+1:end) = g(1:k+1:end) * Eps;
```

Edit:

Also a cell array of function handles can be created.

You can create a diagonal matrix of `Eps` and for each row you can return a function handle that accepts `x` as input and returns `f(x+row)`.

```
f = @(x) x(1) + x(2)^2 ;
k = 2;   %  k = numel(x)
Eps = 1e-10;
g = cell (1, k);
d = diag(repmat(Eps,1,k));
for ii = 1 : k
    g{ii} = @(x)f(d(ii,:)+x);
end
```

All in one line:

```
g = cellfun(@(y){@(x)f(y+x)},num2cell(diag(repmat(Eps,1,k)),2));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't have any fixed values for `X`. Ultimately I will need to feed `g` into a solver to find the optimal values of `x` -- i.e. `fminunc(@(x) g(x) * eye(k) * g(x)', zeros(1, k))`. I will edit my question.